# unable to install bootloader, grub dev/sda

Tags: grub2, system-installation

I'm having trouble installing Ubuntu. every time it goes well, till it tries to execute `grub-install /dev/sda`. after about one and a half hours it says:

```
Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda
Executing `grub-install /dev/sda` failed.
This is a fatal error.
```

My computer is having trouble booting - I've seen this problem about three times in a row:

```
[   82.890016] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 63
[   82.890021] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 7, async page read
[   82.890040] ata1: EH complete
[  138.832445] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1c0000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  138.832516] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[  138.832554] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  138.832604] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:90:38:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 18 ncq4096 in
                        res 41/40:00:3f:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[  138.832727] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  138.832762] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[  138.838261] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  138.838285] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#18 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK 
driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  138.838289] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#18 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[descriptor] 
[  138.838293] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#18 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[  138.838298] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#18 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 38 00 00 08 00
[  138.838301] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 63
[  138.838358] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 7, async page read
[  138.838444] ata1: EH complete
```

I tried to format the whole disk, but it says:

```
Error wiping device: Command-line `wipefs -a "/dev/sda"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: wipefs: error: /dev/sda: probing initialization failed: Device or resource busy
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error messages seem to indicate a failing disk drive specifically issues accessing sector 63 which will be inside the MBR unfortunately that rules out workarounds like badblocks should that be the case.

I'd recommend that you use smart to test the drive, to do so boot the machine using the live CD then type this command to install the smart tools into the live CD environment:

```
sudo apt-get install smartmontools
```

After installation you can run the following command to ask the drive to test itself for problems:

```
sudo smartctl -t long /dev/sda
```

This process will take some time as the drive will perform tests on every sector of the drive, once the test is complete you can check the results with:

```
sudo smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda
```

Should smart testing report a physical error with the drive you might want to give serious consideration to replacing the hardware, once physical sector errors start appearing that are not automatically fixed by the drive internally remapping to spare sectors it is generally a bad sign for the continued longevity and reliability of the drive even if there was some means to work around it.

Comment: thank you for your answer!
after installing it;
to 
"sudo smartctl -t long /dev/sda" 
it said

"sudo smartctl -t long /dev/sda
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [i686-linux-4.4.0-31-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

/dev/sda: Unknown USB bridge [0x0781:0x5572 (0x127)]
Please specify device type with the -d option.

Use smartctl -h to get a usage summary"

Comment: That's strange, is this a USB external hard disk or something? Not seen an error like that before personally.

Comment: nope, it inside my laptop *
fujitsu ESPRIMO Mobile V6535